# FTP: 550 Permissions Denied

Tags: server, ftp, uploading

I'm attempting to upload files to my remote server via FTP, but I continually get blocked from uploading files with "550 Permissions Denied".

The strange part is that it worked at first perfectly, an only now has it stopped working. The user I am logged into has the proper privileges, but I still can't upload.

[image]

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Over quota, perhaps?

Comment: I had the exact same issue with vsftpd. Error 550 no quota problems, no permissions problems but the error was still there.
Uninstalled vsftpd, installed proftpd and everything worked like a charm...

Comment: Good idea. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue with vsftpd. Error 550 no quota problems, no permissions problems but the error was still there. Uninstalled vsftpd, installed proftpd and everything worked like a charm...

Comment: I was expecting to someone to come with an explanation for this behavior, but that's life

Answer (score 1):

A 550 Error means "Requested action not taken. File unavailable, not found, not accessible." Since the file is available that means the server isn't accessible. That most likely means one of the following:

- You have used your Transfer Quota up, Tim Post suggusted this
- You have used up your server space Quota
- Your account has been locked by the hosting company due to some issue like not paying or a clerical mistake on their part (this happens)
- Your host's ftp server is having an authentication issue
- Someone hacked your account or the ftp server.  I have seen this happen but they weren't able to change the ftp passwords.

Check with the hosting company to make sure you have not used up one of your Quotas.  You should be able to do this through their website. If that isn't the case then give them a call and let them know what is happening.  They will be able to check your account and see if it is locked or having some kind of issue.  Usually they will even reset your password for you if that is the issue for some reason.  If this isn't a quota issue then it is probably an issue on their site and contacting them is the fastest way to fix it.

Also, it would be helpful if you give us the name of your host.  If you aren't hosting then you need to log in to your remote server and check on your ftp server software.  It has most likely had an error.

Comment: Thanks, I've rented a server myself (running Ubuntu) and installed vsftpd for the FTP server software. How might I check to find an error with it?

I know I haven't used up my server space quota, but I'm trying to find whether I'm out of bandwidth (though I had 40gb, so I doubt that's the problem).

Comment: @GuyNoir: You should call the company you are renting the server from and ask them how to check or ask them to check for you.

Comment: I have asked them to check my quota statistics, but the server was not rented with an FTP server pre-installed. It came as just a basic Ubuntu installation and left everything up to you. 

Because of that they're not really responsible for any errors in the FTP server itself, unless it had to do with bandwidth.

Comment: I fixed it by using proftpd instead of vsftpd. Strange but it works now. Thanks for the suggestions though.